# Using smart pointers correctly without leaks

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm working on an architecture where I need to have an Entity in different list like that :

- Renderer     -> List of Component (SpriteComponent)
- Collisioner  -> List of Component (PhysicComponent)

I think smart pointer are the best solution to manage all these references, so I started to learn it, but I've got some problems and I'm sor sur if I use them correctly.

---

Explications :

I've got an Abstract class : IEntity

```
class IEntity {
  public:
    IEntity( World& world );
  private:
    World* world;
  public:
    std::tr1::weak_ptr<IEntity> weak_this;
};

typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<IEntity> Entity;
```

And I've got a method to create entities in an EntityManager :

```
Entity EntityManager::createEntity() {
    Entity entity( new IEntity( *this->world ) );
    entity->weak_this = entity;
    this->entityList.add( &entity );
    return entity;
}
```

In my EntityManager class I've got a vector of "Entity" (Of shared_ptr) :

```
std::vector<Entity> entityList;
```

**1 - Did i need to use the type "Entity" everywhere in my program (in parameters, ... ) ?**

**2 - If i have this :**

```
class IComponent {
  public:
    IComponent();    
};
typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<IComponent*> Component;
```

And i've got an object like this :

```
class SpriteComponent : public Component {
  public:
    SpriteComponent();        
    int texture;
};
```

It's good to inherit from a shared_ptr ? It's look strange for me but that work.

**3 - I've tried to create 10000 entities using this :**

```
Entity entity = world.getEntityManager().createEntity();
```

A reference to the entity is push in my vector of "Entity", if I have really understand smart pointer, a clear on vector will remove all Entity (because there isn't other references). But when I look with the cXode leak profiler I can see the memory growing without Entity removed. So I've just tried to create entity withour insertion in my vector and I haven't got leak, why ? Where is the problem ? Oo.

**4 - If i use smart_ptr in a game, did i have some performance issues ? (I'm using references) :**

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

1. I wouldn't call it `Entity`, but maybe `EntityPtr` or some such. (`Entity` sugests that its a concrete implementation of `IEntity`)
2. Don't derive from `Component`, but from `IComponent`. Your `Component` smart pointers will then be able to hold objects of type `SpriteComponent`.
3. A clear on the `EntityManager.entityList` would delete the objects if no other references existsed. But your code seems to be doing something odd when filling the vector.

   ```
   EntityPtr entity( new IEntity( *this->world ) );
   ...
   this->entityList.add( &entity );
   ```

   This adds the address of the entity to the entity list, there should not be a `&` there.
   I'm not sure why this would cause a leak - but its definately wrong.
4. Yes, there is a performance penalty in using smart pointers. But dont worry about it until you can measure it as a problem in your core loops - It may never be enough of a penalty to matter.